# can I use Href in img

Tags: html, image, href

Can I use tag href inside img? because validator does not like it 
Here is the error: 
***Attribute href not allowed on element img at this point.***
and my code:

```html
<div class="img_basked">
<img src="/design/img/prod_basked.png" id="basketing974"                                     onMouseOver="changeImg('/design/img/basket_h',id)"                                   onMouseOut="changeImg('/design/img/prod_basked',id)" alt=""
onclick="addProduct(974, this); return false;"
href="#fancy_basket" class="fancybox"/>
                                </div>
```

Comment: it should be added BEFORE you call the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#fancy_basket" class="fancybox">
<img src="/design/img/prod_basked.png" id="basketing974" /></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is to add a href before image:

```html
<div class="img_basked">
  <a href="#fancy_basket">
     <img src="/design/img/prod_basked.png" id="basketing974"                                                            onMouseOver="changeImg('/design/img/basket_h',id)"                                                                 onMouseOut="changeImg('/design/img/prod_basked',id)" alt=""
                onclick="addProduct(974, this); return false;"
            class="fancybox"/>
    </a>
                                </div>
```